# Angularjs: ng-class not picking up class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the code

```
<body ng-app="app">

        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="n in range" class="test" ng-class="{{($index < 5) && 'visible' || 'invisible' }}" style="display:inline;">
        <a href ="#">{{n.number}}</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

angular code

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.range= [
{number: "1"},
{number: "2"},
{number: "3"},
{number: "4"},
{number: "5"},
{number: "6"},
{number: "7"},
{number: "8"}
];
});
```

I dont see visible or invisible getting added to class, may I know what is the issues

Comment: Double curly braces are for strings.
Try with single curlies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use string interpolation in ng-class (`{{ ... }}`);

This syntax should work:

```
 ng-class="{ visible : ($index < 5), invisible : ($index >= 5) }"
```

But a better approach (IMO) would be set styles from `invisible` class as default styles of that element and apply only `visible` class overwrites.

```
 ng-class="{ visible : $index < 5 }"
```

This will give you a cleaner looking code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this. It will work.

```
ng-class = {($index < 5) ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}
```

or This:

```
ng-class = {visible: (index<5)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it is better to use a directive ng-show or ng-if:

```
<li ng-repeat="n in range" ng-if="$index < 5" style="display:inline;">
```

or

```
<li ng-repeat="n in range" ng-show="$index < 5" style="display:inline;">
```

Comment: What if `visible` / `invisible` is not only responsible for showing an element but for something more?

Comment: I guess for something more you'd better use a different class name.

Comment: By 'something more' I mean something more than `display:none`

Comment: Obviously, when the element is not visible (exactly it means the class name "invisible"), the other css rule useless! In an extreme case, you can easily add the necessary rules for the classes "ng-hide" and "ng-show".